# AWS API Gateway: Why setting "application/json" mapping template for GET request is required for MOCK integration to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I'm setting up a mock integration for GET requests with AWS API Gateway, and wonder why it only works when the `application/json` request template is specified. To my understanding GET request does not have a body and hence does not have a Content-Type header. What is special about 'application/json'? Is this behavior documented somewhere or am I missing some defaults somewhere?

Here is terraform code for my API Gateway:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "test-api" {
  name = "test-api"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }

  body = jsonencode(yamldecode(file("openapi.yaml")))
}
```

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  version: "1.0"
  title: example

paths:
  /test:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: demo
          headers:
            Content-Type: { schema: { type: 'string' } }

      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: MOCK
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_templates
       
        # the next line is required. 
        # API Gateway returns 500 error if I remove it. why? 
        # API Gateway returns 415 error if I change application/json to text/plain. why? 
   
        requestTemplates: { 'application/json': '{"statusCode": 200}' }
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters: { 'method.response.header.Content-Type': "'text/plain'" }
            responseTemplates: {'text/plain': 'hello'}
```

Here is an example log output when requestTemplates is set to`{ 'text/plain': '{"statusCode": 200}' }`

```
Execution log for request 09c6d06b-669c-4717-86a2-c8489136f760
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Starting execution for request: 09c6d06b-669c-4717-86a2-c8489136f760
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /test
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Method request path: {}
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Method request query string: {}
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Method request headers: {}
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Method request body before transformations: 
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Execution failed: null
Fri May 06 14:28:24 UTC 2022 : Method completed with status: 415
```